# push.on('notification') not called from cold start on windows phone universal on Cordova

Tags: cordova, push-notification, windows-phone, win-universal-app, visual-studio-cordova

**Expected Behaviour**

`on('notification')` to be called after init with `launchArgs` when launching app from notification

**Actual Behaviour**

`init` called but not `on('notification')`

**Reproduce Scenario (including but not limited to)**

App is in cold start (removed from app tray) a notification comes in the user will tap on the notification which will launch the app and be directed to a specific screen

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Launch the app
2. Login to the app
3. Put the app into cold start
4. Receive a push notification
5. Tap on the notification
6. App launches to the home screen

**Platform and Version (eg. Android 5.0 or iOS 9.2.1)**

Windows Phone 10 (works on Windows Phone 8.1)

**What device vendor (e.g. Samsung, HTC, Sony...)**

Microsoft Lumia 650

**Cordova CLI version and cordova platform version**

Cordova version 6.1.1

Cordova platform version Windows 4.3.2

phonegap-plugin-push  1.8.2

**Sample Push Data Payload**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <toast launch="xyz">  <visual>   <binding template="ToastText02">    <text id="1">Tile</text>    <text id="2">Message</text>   </binding>  </visual> </toast>`

**Sample Code that illustrates the problem**

default handling of push notification as stated in the documentation

**Logs taken while reproducing problem**

n/a

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cordova-windows@4.4+ as it has [CB-11658 activated event is not fired](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11658) issue fixed.

For coldstart you should use toast' `launch` attribute and subscribe to `activated` cordova event.

See [this comment](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1033#issuecomment-238237978) with usage details.